# Java JSR-82 Implementation (javax.Bluetooth.*) - Using Bluecove

Tags: bluetooth, java, jsr82, bluecove

I am searching for some help with JSR-82. I have searched for a long time, and even had my project supervisor at uni helping me out, and so far, I have had no luck.

My Problem...

I have a project whereby I simply need to scan for Bluetooth Devices

I have not yet been able to get my Bluetooth device scanning. I am using Eclipse IDE in CentOS 5.5 
and am trying to use Bluecove.

I have downloaded "bluecove-gpl-2.1.0.jar" and added it to my Eclipse Build Path and the code i am using is sample code provided by BlueCove (RemoteDeviceDiscovery Found here: http://bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/overview-summary.html#DeviceDiscovery).

Before i can even compile, javax.Bluetooth.*; is underlined suggesting it cannot find it - Now as far as i am aware, this should be within the bluecove jar file i mentioned previously.

How on earth do I get this thing working? Ive tried using JSR82.com but that wasnt much help at all

If any one has the time to assist me, you would be concidered a god! haha

thanks

- Ryan

Answer (score 0):

With bluecove on linux you need to provide the bluecove.jar and bluecove-gpl.jar. http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/wiki/Documentation

Comment: Hi, Thankyou for your answer. I have been reading through the documentation for BlueCove, and although it suggests that both the bluecove.jar and bluecove-gpl.jar are required, on the downloads section of the website, it says that the bluecove-gpl.jar is for linux and bluecove.jar is for windows/Mac... Am i supposed to be adding these to the $CLASSPATH system variable, or can i just get away with adding these to the Eclipse Project build path? Thanks once again - Ryan

Comment: Adding them in eclipse should be fine. From my understanding of whats going on over at bluecove, you need the bluecove.jar to implement any j2se bluetooth support. the bluetooth-gpl.jar is an "extension" of the bluecove.jar that provides access to blueZ driver in linux.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. But ive still got a problem - Im still trying to use Bluecove's code (RemoteDeviceDiscovery), but everytime i compile/run from Eclipse, i got the following error..
Native Library bluecove not available

Exception in thread "main" javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove library bluecove not available

From my understanding, it cannot find Javax.bluetooth.*; but in Eclipse, its not underlining the import for bluetooth.

Although in my JRE Directory (/opt/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/ext) I have put the 2 JAR's aswell..but still no luck. im just getting the same error

Comment: A quick google found this: http://groups.google.com/group/bluecove-users/browse_thread/thread/d55f719fdf590989

Comment: @Ryan, Have you implemented bluecove in android. If so share your experience to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

you will be needing 4 jar files: `bluecove.jar`,`bluecove-emu.jar`,`electricblue.jar`, `javabluetooth.jar`

however my code based on jsr82 implimentation did not work on samsung mobiles.... it is said that it does not support jsr82 stack. if anyone has idea on this share..